# using conditional statement in WHERE clause mysql

Tags: php, mysql

If `keep_base_amount` is null then I want to use `country_id=236` in where clause, else I want to use `keep_base_amount`'s value as in country_id.

I have query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM account_treasury_local
WHERE
CASE WHEN keep_base_amount IS NOT NULL THEN country_id = keep_base_amount
ELSE country_id = '236' END
```

There is a record in database. But, I am getting nothing in result. Is there anything missing/wrong in above query.

Comment: what is the record in your DB? because this should work but I'd prefer to use AND|OR for this and not CASE clause

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this

```
SELECT * FROM account_treasury_local
WHERE (keep_base_amount IS NOT NULL AND country_id = keep_base_amount) OR (keep_base_amount IS NULL AND country_id = '236')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM account_treasury_local
WHERE
  (keep_base_amount IS NOT NULL AND country_id = keep_base_amount)
  OR
  (keep_base_amount IS NULL AND country_id = '236')
```

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly.